# Converting a Query to LINQ

Tags: linq, lambda

How can I convert the following query in a Linq with Lambda ?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Registro, COUNT(Registro) as qnt 
FROM XML_Relatorio
WHERE Arquivo = 'redenet.xml' 
AND TipoErro <> 'Imovel Inserido' 
AND TipoErro <> 'TI'
AND DataHora BETWEEN '01-01-2012' AND '02-01-2012' 
GROUP BY Registro 
ORDER BY Registro
```

I'm trying the following code, but I need some help to build the LINQ with Lambda

```
IQueryable<XML_Relatorio> quantidadeErro = db.XML_Relatorios
    .Where(a => a.Arquivo == "redenet.xml" 
           && a.TipoErro != "Imovel Inserido" 
           && a.TipoErro != "TI");
```

Comment: Which bit are you having problems with?

Comment: The `BETWEEN` in the `DataHora` column is a problem, look my update

Comment: Sounds like you are best off by learning a bit more about LINQ in general. Someone here might give you the answer once but this does not help you in the long run. Why don't you Google for "LINQ group by"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing the `DataHora` field is of `Date` or `DateTime` type.

```
// parse the strings to datetime 
var start = DateTime.Parse("01-01-2012");
var end = DateTime.Parse("02-01-2012");

IQueryable<XML_Relatorio> quantidadeErro = db.XML_Relatorios
   .Where(a => a.Arquivo == "redenet.xml" 
       && a.TipoErro != "Imovel Inserido" 
       && a.TipoErro != "TI"
       // and compare them...
       && a.DataHora > start && a.DataHora < end);
```